# ServiceProviderExtensions GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext> to IdentityDbConext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a problem in .NET core 6. I need my serviceProvider to convert a custom DatabaseContext to an IdentityDbContext.

I have a similiar situation in project A, where it works. In project B it does not work

project A:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext //DbContext is of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

in Program.cs

```
services.TryAddScoped<DbContext>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>());
```

works.

project B:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>> //AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

in Program.cs

```
services.TryAddScoped<IdentityDbContext>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>()); //services is of IServiceCollection
```

leads to Error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'DatabaseContext' to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext'`

Why is it possible to convert DatabaseContext of project A to DbContext, but not possible to convert DatabaseContext to IdentityDbContext in project B?

I want to use the service in a nuget package, which I created by myself. A workaround that works, but is ugly as hell, is to include the code of the package in the main project and don't use `IdentityDbContext` in it but directly the custom `DatabaseContext`.

Comment: It works in project A because `DatabaseContext` is a `DbContext`, but it doesn't work in project b because `DatabaseContext` is *not* a `IdentityDbContext`. It is a `IdentityDbContext<,,,,,,,>`, but `IdentityDbContext<,,,,,,,>` does not derive from `IdentityDbContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TRoleClaim,TUserToken>` class [inherits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8?view=aspnetcore-6.0) from [`IdentityUserContext<TUser,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserLogin,TUserToken>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityusercontext-5?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which inherits from `DbContext` directly:

```cs
public abstract class IdentityUserContext<TUser,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserLogin,TUserToken> : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext ...
```

So `ProjectB.DatabaseContext` is not an `IdentityDbContext`.